# ¿Hay alguna relación entre el carácter (personalidad) y un caracter (letra)?

Tags: etimología

Aunque se pronuncian distinto, supongo que debe haber alguna relación de significado o histórica entre el **carácter**

> mi suegra tiene muy mal carácter

y un **caracter**

> puedes usar un máximo de 200 caracteres

¿Existe alguna relación?

Comment: nótese que _caracter_ no es una palabra válida. El singular de caracteres (sin tilde) es [_carácter_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7OboGAc) (con ella).

Comment: Tomando la etimología parece que tienen relación: _Del lat. character, y este del gr. χαρακτήρ charaktḗr, der. de χαράττειν charáttein 'hacer una incisión, marcar'._

Comment: Link interesante: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=character&allowed_in_frame=0

Comment: En inglés se diría que existe la variante _caracter_ para la marca física, usada por tales grupos en tales contextos. En castellano, obviamente, decimos que “no es válida”.

Comment: I think we use character in English. In both sense which Rodrigo describes

Comment: @fedorqui y Carlos Alejo: Oops!  Un errorcillo. No creo ser el único que pronuncia _caracter_ como aguda para "letra" y _carácteres_ como esdrújula para "personalidades". Hoy aprendí algo y de paso descubrí que también me equivoco con _especimen_.

Comment: De hecho no creo que se tarde en aceptar _caracter_ (sin tilde) desde el momento que ya se tiene _caracteres_ y _carácteres_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vamos por pasos.

En primer lugar, como ya han apuntado, la palabra *caracter* no existe en castellano, sino que en singular se dice siempre ***[carácter](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=car%C3%A1cter)***, aunque se refiera a los signos de escritura.

En segundo lugar: según la RAE, *carácter* viene del latín *character* y éste del griego *χαρακτήρ*. En griego antiguo, según [el Wikcionario](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%87%CE%B1%CF%81%CE%B1%CE%BA%CF%84%CE%AE%CF%81), la palabra *χαρακτήρ* significa:

- instrumento usado para tallar.
- persona que talla, tallador.
- impresión, estampa, sello.
- reproducción, representación
- figura, letra, carácter.
- característica, carácter
- estilo

Estas dos últimas acepciones nos indican que, efectivamente, ambos significados ya estaban presentes en el griego antiguo. Precisamente el DPD nos dice que, resumidamente, los dos significados de *carácter* son, precisamente, "Conjunto de rasgos característicos" y "signo de la escritura".

El motivo imagino que vendrá dado por el significado de la palabra origen, *χαράττειν*, "hacer una marca". El carácter se forja mediante las "marcas" que va dejando la experiencia en tu vida, y un carácter es una marca en un papel (originalmente los caracteres eran marcas en piedra o madera, lo que acerca el término al sentido de "talla").

Comment: Impecable, gracias. O sea que el carácter "letra" es anterior al carácter "personalidad", nunca me lo habría imaginado.